# Reasons for choosing LES in stead of RANS models?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, numerical-modelling, fluid-dynamics, turbulence

In oceanography, is there any particular reason why choosing large eddy simulations in stead of RANS (regardless of the type of flow)? In both cases, 2d simulations would be used (shallow water model).

What are the pros and contras, in general, of both approaches?

Comment: I think it might be useful to read https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/what-are-the-differences-between-an-les-sgs-model-and-a-rans-based-turbulence-mo and then maybe refocus the question